# How do I solve $x\sin(x)=b$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve $x\sin(x)=b$ for $x$?

This came up while I was trying to solve something else.  It seems simple but I can't figure it out right now.

Comment: No closed-form solution. Furthermore, infinitely many solutions if there is no bound on $x.$

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can only do it numerically via Newton's method or the like, but not algebraically.  Newton's method is very efficient.